# ReferenceError: document is not defined on Bootstrap.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, popper.js, bootstrap-5

I installed bootstrap, popper.js and jquery as indicated on their official pages. Using the npm package manager. But by requiring them in app.js it sends me this error.

> **This is app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');

require('@popperjs/core');
require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

//Initializations.
const app = express();

//Importing routes.
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index.router');

//Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//Midlewares
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Routes
app.use('/', indexRoutes);

//Static Files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Start Server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port: ', app.get('port'));
});
```

> **This is the error.**
> I installed bootstrap, jquery and popper.

> npm install bootstrap@next

> npm i @popperjs/core

> npm install jquery

```
C:\Users\erve\Desktop\NodeJS\Facebook\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:257
  var isRTL = document.documentElement.dir === 'rtl';
              ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at C:\Users\erve\Desktop\NodeJS\Facebook\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:257:15
    at C:\Users\erve\Desktop\NodeJS\Facebook\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:7:83
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\erve\Desktop\NodeJS\Facebook\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:10:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\erve\Desktop\NodeJS\Facebook\app.js:8:1)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```